python flask trial
вот мой код, когда запускаю с телефона воспроизведения аудио потока, каждые несколько секунд слышу то ли trial, то ли tryel, вообще помогите пожалуйста, как исправить это?
main.py
from flask import Flask, Response, render_template
import pyaudio

app = Flask(__name__)  # Исправлено на __name__

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
CHUNK = 1024
RECORD_SECONDS = 1

audio1 = pyaudio.PyAudio()

def genHeader(sampleRate, bitsPerSample, channels):
    datasize = 2000 * 10**6
    o = bytes("RIFF", 'ascii')                                               # (4byte) Marks file as RIFF
    o += (datasize + 36).to_bytes(4, 'little')                               # (4byte) File size in bytes excluding this and RIFF marker
    o += bytes("WAVE", 'ascii')                                              # (4byte) File type
    o += bytes("fmt ", 'ascii')                                              # (4byte) Format Chunk Marker
    o += (16).to_bytes(4, 'little')                                          # (4byte) Length of above format data
    o += (1).to_bytes(2, 'little')                                           # (2byte) Format type (1 - PCM)
    o += (channels).to_bytes(2, 'little')                                    # (2byte)
    o += (sampleRate).to_bytes(4, 'little')                                  # (4byte)
    o += (sampleRate * channels * bitsPerSample // 8).to_bytes(4, 'little')  # (4byte)
    o += (channels * bitsPerSample // 8).to_bytes(2, 'little')               # (2byte)
    o += (bitsPerSample).to_bytes(2, 'little')                               # (2byte)
    o += bytes("data", 'ascii')                                              # (4byte) Data Chunk Marker
    o += (datasize).to_bytes(4, 'little')                                    # (4byte) Data size in bytes
    return o

@app.route('/audio')
def audio():
    def sound():
        sampleRate = 44100
        bitsPerSample = 16
        channels = 2
        wav_header = genHeader(sampleRate, bitsPerSample, channels)

        stream = audio1.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
                              rate=RATE, input=True, input_device_index=1,
                              frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
        print("recording...")
        first_run = True
        try:
            while True:
                if first_run:
                    data = wav_header + stream.read(CHUNK)
                    first_run = False
                else:
                    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
                yield data
        except GeneratorExit:
            print("Stream closed.")
        finally:
            stream.stop_stream()
            stream.close()

    return Response(sound(), mimetype="audio/wav")

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":  # Исправлено на __name__ == "__main__"
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False, threaded=True, port=5000)
    

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <audio controls>
        <source src="{{ url_for('audio') }}" type="audio/wav">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
</body>
</html>

